# How do you set up Portal 2 split-screen co-op on a PC?

Tags: pc, portal-2, cheats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we play Portal 2 co-op on one iMac?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20769/can-we-play-portal-2-co-op-on-one-imac)

According to this [article](http://www.co-optimus.com/article/5942/how-to-play-portal-2-split-screen-on-your-pc.html) and this [steam forum thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1847904), it's possible to set up a split-screen co-op in Portal 2 on the PC. To clarify: This is having 2 people on one PC with the same steam instance of Portal 2 both controlling their own character in the co-op campaign mode of the game.

It's not supported out of the box by the menu interface. However, many have apparently gotten this to work by having either an XBox 360 PC USB controller or a gamepad controller that is configured to emulate one.

The original forum post seems to work for most people, but not in all circumstances. There seem to be a lot of other threads in the wild with many different solutions.

I figured G.SE would be a good place to post all the possible solutions and maybe arrive at a definitive method or process to follow to get this to work.

Comment: The OS's are different, but the answer is the same.

Comment: @RavenDreamer One of them, at any rate.

Comment: Wait, what don't you get? You included a link of how to do what you want...

Comment: Did you actually READ the forum threads? The steam forums have NOT nailed down the exact solution that works for all instances and the solution post is sloppy and managed by one person, Many have gotten it to work through trial and error. I figured gaming.stackexchange could do a better job than the steam forums by using its voting mechanism to help the community narrow down the definitive solution that works for all. But I guess link references to a forum in the wild are good enough for you. Anyways good luck nailing a solution down with the 11% of the steam population that is Mac users.