# Assign wired Xbox 360 controller as controller 2 on Linux

Tags: controllers, linux

There are a few co-op games I'd like to play with family/friends, but since it's not possible to use separate machines for all games and they do support controllers, I would like to allow the second player to use the controller (there is only one in the house, a wired Xbox 360 controller). But the problem with that is that most games force controller #1 to be player #1, but the keyboard and mouse would also be player #1. Thus, the controller and keyboard will be fighting to control the same player.

I have no idea if this will allow me to play local co-op games with only one controller, but if I could force the controller to become controller #2, I could at least experiment game-by-game what would work with that.

So can I, in Linux (Ubuntu 16.10 or Debian Stretch), force a single wired Xbox controller to be controller #2?

Comment: I have no problems doing this with [Screencheat](http://store.steampowered.com/app/301970/), is there a specific game you have an issue with?

Comment: Portal 2 and Death Road To Canada act this way. I don't own Screencheat (how do you play that split-screen!?), but Never Alone allows the keyboard and mouse to be used by the primary player and the controller by the sidekick. Separate research into Portal 2 local co-op has been inconclusive on how to use K&M + controller, or even if it's possible. DR2C is an indie game, so there is little hope of being able to Google about it.

Comment: It might be better then to ask a question about a single game, since it might vary by game. For example, it can be done in Left For Dead with a [config file](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=745113).

Comment: Like I said, some games don't provide an easy way for normal players to do that. While I may be able to use the L4D solution for Portal 2, the same is not true for DR2C. Also if I can assign the controller number system-wide, I could get all sorts of ancient games to handle a second player without sharing the keyboard. This question is more about experimentation and possibilities than the actual games.

Comment: [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20769/can-we-play-portal-2-co-op-on-one-pc-or-mac/185446#185446) covers portal 2, maybe if you ask specifically about DR2C someone can answer for that

Comment: @Angzuril Actually it didn't work for Portal 2. All it did was enter split screen move with no control for player 2 and both the keyboard and the controller bound to player 1. Back to square 1.

Comment: @StephenAngelico - With L4D I was able to work around it by plugging in two Xbox controllers, and just ignoring the first one and using the keyboard/mouse. Any chance that would work for your solution?

Comment: @Robotnik No, I only have one controller. If I could ignore one I would. Is there perhaps some way to emulate a dummy controller in software?

Comment: I realize this is old and possibly no longer needed / not exactly what you are asking for, but thought I'd mention as relevant in case others come in from search: for games that support having P1 and P2 on same keyboard, then a workaround you could use is to disable SDL via wine/proton which will hide the controller from the game. You could then run a controller to keyboard mapping app such as antimicro/antimicrox. Here are some [notes](https://github.com/zpangwin/antimicro-profiles/tree/master/beyond-good-and-evil) where I disabled SDL to hide native mappings in a single player game.

Comment: Okay, that's cool for sure, but that unfortunately doesn't work in Portal 2. Also Valve release Remote Play Together, which theoretically (except that it's fragile) does that same job more conveniently (and Steam can configure controllers to map to keyboard actions). As for playing co-op games with family... well the people I play with ended up getting their own copies of those games. If you can afford it, it's a better experience.
I am curious as to whether there are other consequences to disabling SDL though - is SDL is still an important part of the Linux graphics stack?